# Why can't I grep the tmux man page for join-pane?

Tags: grep, tmux, man

If I type `man tmux` then `/join-pane` I go right to the subcommand I'm looking for:

[image]

But if I grep the man page then I get nothing:

```
$ man tmux | grep join-pane
$ echo $?
1
```

If I try something different then it does work:

```
$ man tmux | grep 'terminal multiplexer'
     tmux -- terminal multiplexer
     tmux is a terminal multiplexer: it enables a number of terminals to be
```

- What is going on here?
- Why can't I grep the tmux man page for join-pane?

Some details about my operating system and the commands I'm using:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin home.local 17.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
$ man --version
man, version 1.6c
$ tmux -V
tmux 2.7
```

As per a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459746/why-cant-i-grep-the-tmux-man-page-for-join-pane?noredirect=1#comment835986_459746) about this being a terminal issue I tried some more patterns that didn't work:

```
$ man tmux | grep join\-pane
$ man tmux | grep "join-pane"
$ man tmux | grep 'join-pane'
$ man tmux | grep 'join\-pane'
$ man tmux | grep "join\-pane"
$ man tmux | grep -e join-pane
```

Comment: I guessed your terminal issue. did you try with "join-pane" or join\-pane? it worked for me as well

Comment: `grep --version`? Cannot reproduce this with `grep (GNU grep) 2.25` and `man 2.7.5`. Did you try `grep -e join-pane` yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
 man tmux | col -b | grep -e 'join-pane'
```

man pages have buffer objects like `^H` to emulate bold and underlined characters by backspacing and overstriking.

- `col` will filter out those buffers.

you can check the difference by copying the man page into a file.

with buffer:

```
 man tmux > file1
```

without buffers:

```
 man tmux | col -b > file2
```